# Java method returning char complaining about not returning char.

Tags: java, methods, char

Why is this function complaining that it should return a result of type char?

```
public static char getUserResponseToGuess(int guess){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     
    char userResponse = 'x';            
    while((userResponse != 'h' && userResponse != 'l' && userResponse != 'c')){
        System.out.print("Is it" + guess + "? (h/l/c)");        
        userResponse = input.next().charAt(0);
        if (userResponse == 'h' || userResponse == 'l' || userResponse =='c'){
            return userResponse;            
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Is it" + guess + "? (h/l/c)");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The static analysis done by the compiler does not understand the logic you have used, so based on its analysis all the possible flows does not end up returning a value

When the compiler analysis the code, if the `if` condition in the code is not satisfied and the loop is exited then the method won't return a value.

```
public static char getUserResponseToGuess(int guess){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     
    char userResponse = 'x';            
    while((userResponse != 'h' && userResponse != 'l' && userResponse != 'c')){
        System.out.print("Is it" + guess + "? (h/l/c)");        
        userResponse = input.next().charAt(0);
        if (userResponse == 'h' || userResponse == 'l' || userResponse =='c'){
            return userResponse;            
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Is it" + guess + "? (h/l/c)");
        }
    }
    return userResponse;  
}
```

Comment: If you help the compiler a bit (e.g. by doing a `while (true)`) it also does not complain.

Comment: @vanza ... could you please expand a little on this concept?

Comment: A `while (true)` loop never finishes, unless you explicitly do it with a `return` or a `break`. The compiler sees that the only way out of your loop is a `return`, so it doesn't complain about the lack of a return value.

Comment: Oh wow. I'm kind new to Java. I didn't know a return statement also would get me out of the loop. Good to know. ;)

Comment: Now that Im thinking about this is kind what Arun is doing.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when the `userResponse` is not one of those three characters? It will exit the loop and return what? Every path has to return a `char`

Comment: When it's not one of those characters the code will execute the `return` statement inside the loop.

Comment: Oops, the opposite. If it's not one of those, it will remain inside the loop until it is, then it executes the `return` statement.

Comment: The compiler isn't smart enough to walk through all the logic and know that it must return.

Comment: that's true, but that's not what your answer says. Your answer assumes his code is wrong, which is not the case; it's just the compiler that's not smart enough to understand it.

Comment: Well, that's what the question was about: why doesn't it compile. It doesn't compile not because it's logically wrong, but because the compiler isn't smart enough. There is a difference between those two.

Answer (score 0):

This worked as it should. Arun P Johny solutions also works.

```
public static char getUserResponseToGuess(int guess){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     
    char userResponse = 'x';            
    System.out.print("Is it " + guess + "? (h/l/c): ");
    while((userResponse != 'h' && userResponse != 'l' && userResponse != 'c')){             
        userResponse = input.next().charAt(0);
        if (userResponse == 'h' || userResponse == 'l' || userResponse =='c'){
            break;                          
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Is it " + guess + "? (h/l/c): ");
        }
    }
    return userResponse;    
}
```